# Why is there no proper PPA for automatic mainline kernel updates?

Tags: apt, kernel, updates, dpkg, ppa

Yes, I realize there is a mainline kernel "PPA" : [Kernel / MainlineBuilds | Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds)

But why isn't it possible to add this "PPA" just like any other PPA and get automatic updates through the regular software updates?

Comment: You could ask the kernel team directly, but you will probably want to be more courteous than you have been here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think most users would want their kernel upgraded every Sunday night. For myself I just upgrade if the new version corrects a specific glitch or adds a specific function I can benefit.

The link I will be using later today is http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7.2/

Comment: Most users probably wouldn't even use Ubuntu, let alone use PPAs..., that doesn't mean there is no demand for it. I get automatic upgrades for the graphic drivers via the Oibaf PPA for example. So, I also want automatic updates for the latest kernels.

Comment: A lot of vendors roll driver updates into the kernel as well. Out of curiousitity did the different link I provided than the one you posted prove more beneficial or not?

Comment: No, your link did not prove more beneficial. I know how to install mainline kernels, and there are a lot of examples for how to do it on the internet, for example: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/install-linux-kernel-4-6-ubuntu-16-04/ . What I want to know is how to get automatic updates from the mainline kernels. I don't want to do this manually. There's even a script for this, see: https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater . But I don't like that. I want to get automatic updates via the regular software updates, just like with any other PPA.